# View customization with securesocial & play 2

Tags: playframework-2.0, securesocial

I would like to customize securesocial views.
I can't find how to specify the action URL for my forms.

When I try :

```
<form action="@routes.securesocial.controllers.Registration.handleSignUp(token)"
      class="form-horizontal" autocomplete="off" method="POST">
```

In the route file I configure the route :

```
POST    /signup/:token     securesocial.controllers.Registration.handleSignUp(token)
```

I have the error :

```
value securesocial is not a member of object controllers.routes
```

I don't find any samples.

How can I configure my form action? Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 0):

Given the SecureSocial project views, you should use

```
@securesocial.core.providers.utils.RoutesHelper.handleSignUp(token)
```

in your own view.

I haven't tried but at least the project is successfully compiled.

Comment: When I try to replace `@routes.securesocial.controllers.Registration.handleSignUp(token)` with `@securesocial.core.providers.utils.RoutesHelper.handleSignUp(token)`, there is the following error : `object core is not a member of package controllers.securesocial`

Comment: `@securesocial.core.providers.utils.RoutesHelper.handleSignUp(token).absoluteURL(securesocial.core.IdentityProvider.sslEnabled)` works fine with my project and is confirmed by the official doc http://securesocial.ws/guide/views-customization.html. Have you checked your project's configuration and dependencies?